# Let $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of all non-singular $2×2$ matrices with real entries.Show that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a normal subgroup of

Tags: group-theory, problem-solving, normal-subgroups

Let $GL(2,\mathbb {R})$ denote the set of all non-singular $2×2$ matrices with real entries.Show that $$SL(2,\mathbb{R})=\{\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}\in GL(2,\mathbb {R}),ad-bc=1\}$$ is a normal subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb {R})$ .

In this problem, it is easy to see that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb {R})$ . Now, in order to show that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ as a normal subgroup we must show that $\forall A\in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$, $ASA^{-1}\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, $\forall S\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. Now, if we try to do the calculation of $ASA^{-1}$ , by considering $S=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}
p & q \\
r & s
\end{bmatrix}$ , it becomes an absurdly long calculation. Is there any other way to do this ....I am not quite getting this...There may be a lot of posts concerning the same topic but I can't seem to find it either...

Comment: There’s a problem.  You’ve incorrectly defined the General Linear group.  It consists of non-singular matrices.  As defined in your question, it’s not a group at all because it has elements that aren’t invertible.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you! That was a typo ...maybe I missed it somehow...but thanks for pointing it out...I have edited it...

Comment: Again, Franklin, please work on your punctuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we just need $MSM^{-1} \in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ for $S \in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. we can use the determinant property: $det(MSM^{-1}) = det(S)  = 1$. Hence $MSM^{-1} \in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

We are just using the property $det(AB) = det(A) det(B)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it now...Thank you...